# sql unpivot table error conflict

Tags: sql, t-sql, unpivot

I am running the below unpivot scode but it errors with 
    "The type of column "TransDate" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list " Can someone advise what I need to convert etc? I seems to not like the datetime column transdate. everything else is nvarchar in the table.

```
select  DataLoadSysId, DataLoadBatchSysId, Rowid, ColumnName, ColumnValue As ColumnValue
from (
      select ExtractSource, RecordTypeNo, RecordLevel1Code, RecordLevel2Code, TransDate,
      MainAccount, Amount, PeriodCode, DataAreaId, SourceFile, DataLoadBatchSysId, LoadDate, ValidationErrors, DataLoadSysId, RowId
      from [Staging].[FactFinancialsCoded_Abbas_InitialValidationTest]
) x
UNPIVOT
(
     ColumnValue
     FOR ColumnName 
     IN ([ExtractSource], [RecordTypeNo], [RecordLevel1Code], [RecordLevel2Code], [TransDate], [MainAccount], [Amount], [PeriodCode], [DataAreaId])
)
As UnpivotExample
```

Comment: Could your provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: All columns should have similar datatype, so unpivot requires data type to be consistent, you can repeat cast for all columns in first subquery `cast( TransDate as varchar(55)) TransDate`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Ihad to cast the field and also make it the same length as the rest

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of the `unpivot` keyword.  I find it easier to just use `apply`:

```
select ivt.DataLoadSysId, ivt.DataLoadBatchSysId, ivt.Rowid,
       v.ColumnName, v.ColumnValue
from [Staging].[FactFinancialsCoded_Abbas_InitialValidationTest]  ivt CROSS APPLY
      (VALUES ('ExtractSource', ExtractSource),
              ('RecordTypeNo', RecordTypeNo),
              ('RecordLevel1Code', RecordLevel1Code),
              ('RecordLevel2Code', RecordLevel2Code),
              ('TransDate', TransDate),
              ('MainAccount', MainAccount),
              ('Amount', Amount),
              ('PeriodCode', PeriodCode),
              ('DataAreaId', DataAreaId)
     ) v(columname, columnvalue);
```

This doesn't fix the problem.  I prefer this because `apply` is very powerful and unpivoting is one convenient application to learn about the syntax (technically implementing "lateral joins").

Your problem is competing types.  You need to convert everything to a string.  I can only guess what some of the non-string values are, but something like:

```
select ivt.DataLoadSysId, ivt.DataLoadBatchSysId, ivt.Rowid,
       v.ColumnName, v.ColumnValue
from [Staging].[FactFinancialsCoded_Abbas_InitialValidationTest]  ivt CROSS APPLY
      (VALUES ('ExtractSource', ExtractSource),
              ('RecordTypeNo', RecordTypeNo),
              ('RecordLevel1Code', RecordLevel1Code),
              ('RecordLevel2Code', RecordLevel2Code),
              ('TransDate', convert(varchar(255), TransDate)),
              ('MainAccount', MainAccount),
              ('Amount', convert(varchar(255), Amount)),
              ('PeriodCode', PeriodCode),
              ('DataAreaId', DataAreaId)
     ) v(columname, columnvalue);
```